# How to make the second row of an array point to the first row in C

Tags: java, c, arrays, pointers, object

This works in Java:

```
int a[][]=new int[2][4];
a[1]=a[0];
```

But in C it doesn't work.
Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C/C++, one declares a two dimensional array the same as in JAVA, but the memory allocation by the compiler is different.  E.g., in C one declares a two-dimensional array of int as a contiguous block of memory.

```
int a[][]=new int[2][4]
```

is allocated as contiguous block of 32(2*4*4)bytes. It has only only one reference pointing to the block beginning. If you want to access an element at (i,j) then it returns the value at reference a+(i*2+j).

But in java it allocates a array of 2 pointers and allocates each row again.

```
a= new int[2][];
a[0] = new int[4];
a[1] = new int[4];
```

So you can modify the references for each row.

But in C++ also you can achieve the JAVA behavior by using the following code.

```
int **a = new int*[2];
a[0] = new int[4];
a[1] = new int[4];
a[0] = a[1];
```

If you need in C you should be able to do the same thing with malloc.

Answer (score 0):

In C++:

```
int **a  = new int*[2];
a[0] = new int[4];
a[1] = a[0];
```

In C:

```
int **a  = malloc(2*sizeof(*a));
a[0] = malloc(4*sizeof(*a[0])];
a[1] = a[0];
```